# Is it possible to return hjmpTS, aCLTS, propTS fields using Flexible Search in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm beginner in hybris and I noticed that the queries using `select * from {itemType}` returns the following fields named `hjmpts`, `aCLTS` and `propTS`. But when I use `select {hjmpts}, {aCLTS}, {propTS} from {itemType}` the hybris returns that these fields don't exist.

Does someone know if it is possible to create a Flexible Search to return `hjmpts`, `aCLTS` and `propTS` fields?

Comment: Maybe if you omit the curly brackets for the fields? But why would you do that?

Comment: Thank you. it worked like a charm. I'm studying queries using Flexible Search and I could not understand why these columns are used and why they were not displayed in the query return, but using * they appear. They are probably Hybris internal control columns.

Comment: Those columns are all part of the underlying Hybris persistence layer.  The 'ts' bit means timestamp and they are different counter/versions fields for different areas of the way the type is persisted to the database.  They are managed at a layer well below anything you see when developing in Hybris

Answer (score 0):

This one works in HAC:

```
SELECT hjmpts, aclts, propTS FROM {Employee}
```

These attributes are not Type attributes. If you look at the Type's attributes in Backoffice, you won't see them. This might be why you don't need to include the curly braces.

It's also possible to mix it with Type attributes:

```
SELECT hjmpts, aclts, propTS, {uid} FROM {Employee}
```